# Next.js with Axios Interceptor Not Updating Cached Data in Production Build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, axios, next.js13

I am working on a Next.js 14.0.4 (react ^18) project where I'm using the Axios library for fetching data from the server. To manage API requests, I've implemented Axios interceptors for authentication and error handling. However, I've encountered an issue where my production build consistently serves old data, despite data updates occurring on the server every hour.

I understand that Next.js caches GET requests by default for one hour, and I've attempted to configure revalidation using the dynamic and revalidate flags as mentioned in the Next.js documentation. However, these flags only seem to work with the fetch method, not with Axios.

Here's how I've configured my interceptor:

```
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import axios from "axios";
import { AUTH_TOKEN_KEY, BASE_URL } from "@/config";
import { logoutHandler } from "@/helpers";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import { protectedRoutes } from "@/helpers/constants";

const isServer = typeof window === "undefined";
const api = axios.create();

// request interceptor method:
api.interceptors.request.use(
 async function (config) {
    config.baseURL = BASE_URL;
    if(isServer){
      const {cookies} = await import('next/headers');
      const token = cookies().get(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY)?.value;       
      config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + token;
    }else{
      const token = Cookies.get(AUTH_TOKEN_KEY);
    
      if (token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = "Bearer " + token;
      }
    }
    config.headers['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache';
    config.headers['Pragma'] = 'no-cache';
    config.headers['Expires'] = '0';
    return config;
  },
  function (error) {
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// response interceptor method:
api.interceptors.response.use(
  function (res) {
    return res.data;
  },
  function (error) {
    if(!isServer){
      const activeSplittedPath = window?.location?.pathname?.split('/');
      const isPathInProtectedRoutes = activeSplittedPath.some(pathSegment => protectedRoutes.includes(`/${pathSegment}`));
  
    // If API Gives Error Between 400 to 500 and not 404 then showing toast with Error 
      if(error?.response?.status !== 404 && error?.response?.status > 400 && error?.response?.status < 500){
        toast.error(error?.response?.data?.message);
        // window.location.href = '/login';

        // Page Route That is Requesting data is Protected Then Hiting Logging out User
          if (isPathInProtectedRoutes) {
            setTimeout(() => {
              logoutHandler();
            }, 2000);
          }
      }
    }
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

export { api };
```

And here's how I'm utilizing the interceptor in my API calls:

```
import { api } from "@/lib/api";

const { events } = API_ENDPOINTS;

// get all events
const getEvents = (query) => {
  const queryParam = query ? serialize(query) : "";
  return api.get(`${events.event}${queryParam}`);
};
```

I'm seeking guidance on how to ensure that my production build reflects the most recent data from the server without relying solely on browser cache invalidation. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

I just want re validation should work with axios also